# How can I ask multiple questions in the same "question"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have asked multiple questions in the following thread:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/408184/server-side-javascript-rendering-ssr-from-java

Since I have no previous experience on the subject, there is a chance that one of the questions does n't have an answer. So Instead of creating two similar thread with the same content and different questions, I decided to ask 2 questions in the same thread. An answer to any of those questions is enough, and I believe that to some extent, they are complementary.

It took **less than a minute** to get a negative vote and assumed that that the problem is the multiple questions.

My question is: How could I improve that question?

**Note:** Update the question has been deleted. This is a summary of it:

> I have been checking technologies for JavaScript server-side rendering
>   (SSR) with a headless browser from a Java application in order to
>   compare performance over other SSR solutions.
>
> The only technology I have consistently come across is Selenium but It
>   seems to be designed for testing purposes and I have not seen any
>   reference, recommendation, suggestion or even demonstration about
>   using it for JavaScript server-side rendering. This points me to the
>   conclusion that using Selenium for JavaScript SSR is not a common
>   practice, and therefore, it is discouraged, but I haven't found any
>   reference to back this conclusion either.
>
> So, my questions are:
>
> - Is is there any recommendation against or in favour of using Selenium for SSR?
> - Is there any other Java framework for JavaScript SSR that I have overlooked?

Comment: see also: [How to handle a question that asks many things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267059/839601) at MSO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That question isn't being down voted and closed (and deleted) because you are asking multiple questions, but because you are asking a question that [is specifically called out as one that should not be asked here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Questions that ask others to find or recommend resources (which include tools, frameworks, and libraries) are not permitted here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be a valid question to ask if Selenium can be used for server side rendering? I understand what you mean but I don't know how I can make a valid question on this matter.

Comment: @JCalcines We don't support tools here. So asking how to do anything or make Selenium do anything would be off-topic.

Comment: Actually, In the first question, I wasn't asking how but If it is a good or bad practice to do it. I didn't find any use case for it and people with more knowledge of the tool might help me to understand why should or shouldn't use it. The second question is still out of scope

Comment: @JCalcines Ah. It's kind of right on the edge. I don't have enough experience with Selenium to know if this kind of thing would be considered obvious. If you do some research and find out what other people are saying first, I think that it may be OK. But as you add more and more details making it more unique to your situation, it also gets to the point where it loses value for other people, making it not a good fit. I think it could go either way, honestly.